# Is it common for people to down-vote because they have a competing answer?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

I suspect this is happening to me because I there are no comments under my answer.

I think users should only be allowed to down-vote if they leave a comment as to why.

Comment: People down-vote for all sorts of reasons and don't have to leave a comment. Also - do you have a specific example. But be warned - if you answer is wrong it will get more down-votes by bringing it to meta's attention.

Comment: Why do you suspect this is happening? Why do you suspect that instead of the more logical theory that **they just don't like your answer**? As I've said dozens of times, downvotes are anonymous for a reason. And they're going to stay that way.

Comment: Well, I think it 'might' have happened to me once, but it already had been voted up.  happening is maybe a strong term.

Comment: There are no older -2 downvotes shown in http://stackoverflow.com/users/560383/tomwrong?tab=reputation , so maybe someone just took back their upvote in that case you remember.

Comment: Note that there is such a thing as "tactical downvoting", e.g. voting competing answers down temporarily in order to get more visibility for an answer, then removing the downvote within the limited window where that's possible. This is antisocial behavior that's frowned on, but not *that* common.

Comment: You might be interested in [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132438/stack-exchange-community-statistics-results-how-sportsmanlike-are-our-users) which presents some actual statistics on competitive voting from the SO database.

Answer (score 5):

I could only find [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705389/how-do-i-stop-cursor-blinking-in-linux-console-ex-a-cygwin/6705435#6705435) of yours with a downvote, and that answer is a joke answer that isn't really useful. This is most probably also the reason it got downvoted, and why it will continue to be downvoted further.

There is no reason to assume this downvote comes from a "competitor", and I couldn't find any other downvotes on your answers.

Comment: Nice find. Added my -1, but didn't leave a comment.

Comment: @tomwrong - see, I told you to be careful about bringing this up.

Comment: Looks like I've got a lot to learn ChrisF.  I've only started to use stackoverflow to vent otherwise boring pub conversation.